# Execute several promises in parallel, but only retrieve result from one of them

Tags: javascript, typescript, concurrency, promise

I currently have a program where I want to call several REST API:s in parallel, but I'm only interested in the result from one of them.

Currently I've solved it like this:

```
private async loadData () {
    const all = [this.loadFirstData(), this.loadSecondData(), this.loadThirdData()];
    const combine = Promise.all(all);
    await combine;

    // One of the promises just puts it's return value in this global variable, so that I can access it after it is done.
    if (this.valueFromThirdAPI) {
        // Do something with value
    }
}
```

So  what I do is just put the put the result from the promise I want a result from in a global variable that I can access after all of the promises have returned. This works, but I'm sure there must be a much better way of doing this.

`Promises.all` returns a array of the resolved values, but how do I distinguish them from each other if I'm only interested in the value from one of them? The other two doesn't need to return anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it makes sense to await Promise.all,

You can access the result using the returned array's index.
Another option is using Array destructoring.

Below is an example..

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const promise2 = Promise.resolve(2);
const promise3 = Promise.resolve('this one');
const promise4 = Promise.resolve(4);

async function test() {
  //note the double `,` to ignore the first 2 promises.
  const [,,three] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4]);
  console.log(three);
}

test();
```

Comment: This is as clean as it gets, I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` returns an array with the same order of the given promises:

```
private async loadData () {
    const all = [this.loadFirstData(), this.loadSecondData(), this.loadThirdData()];
    const combine = Promise.all(all);
    const values = await combine;

    // One of the promises just puts it's return value in this global variable, so that I can access it after it is done.
    if (values[2]) {
        // Do something with value
    }
}
```

Comment: Might also be an idea to do -> `const combine = await Promise.all(all);` and remove the `await combine` otherwise `combine` is still just going to be the promise.

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to change as little as possible so OP sees what is happening.

Comment: Maybe, but the above as is wont work, combine is a Promise not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the return values when they are all resolved.
Promise.all().then(values)
Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Moving away from `async / await`, to thenables seems a step backwards don't you think?

Comment: Maybe, async/await is very good, but the thenables still works.

Answer (score 1):

Wait on the third and then await on all. So if the third finishes before first and second, you get to process it earlier.

```
private async loadData () {
    const all = [this.loadFirstData(), this.loadSecondData(), this.loadThirdData()];
    const third = await all[2];
    if (third) {
        // Do something with value
    }

    await Promise.all(all);
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea if you want early process of 3rd,.  But one thing to note.  Third could still get processed if 1 & 2 fail, so even though you might not be interested in result of 1 & 2, you still may require them to succeed.  IOW: As long as you don't care if 1 & 2 fail this is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, as @Keith said I needed all of them be completed before I used the result of the third promise. But it's good to know that this is possible as well!